# RX Subject<T> How To Cancel a Subscription

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a service that returns a `Subject<T>` and consumer is subscribing to it.
How would I cancel an existing subscription and dispose it?

Comment: Is your code the one subscribing, or you want to unsubscribe someone else's subscription?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you call [Subscribe()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on your `Subject<T>`, it returns an `IDisposable`. Just call Dispose() on the returned handle, and it will cancel the subscription.

Comment: Thank Reed. How efficient is disposing and creating subjects, here is my flow for my RX based Search control.... UserInput -> do Async Search -> while the AsyncSearch is going on if the user searches again -> dispose and recreate the Subject

Comment: @Andy: `Subject<T>`, on it's own, isn't Disposable.  (Of course, a specific one could be).  Disposing the subscription is typically important, as that's how you stop listening - but if it's very decoupled in your design, the GC will probably handle it for you...

Comment: @Andy, if you are trying to abort the search when the user searches again, don't dispose it, consider using TakeUntil. You may want to work through the Hands on Labs to get advice on using services in their dictionary suggest samples.

Comment: The range of `IDisposable` instances returned by `Subscribe` do not call implement the Finalizer part of the Disposable pattern (otherwise subscriptions would be cancelled whenever you didn't store the value). I agree with @Jim in that the preference should be to compose the termination of the sequence into the sequence itself.